# Create sharing rule with apex-mdapi. Issue - required field missing

Tags: apex, metadata-api, sharing-rule

I try to create sharing rule using [apex-mdapi](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi). There is [suitable method in Examples class](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi/blob/3125fc23267096c297e0e2c266cbeee62cc8336e/apex-mdapi/src/classes/MetadataServiceExamples.cls#L1193), anyway it gives me `Variable does not exist: sharedFrom` error. I added **sharedFrom** field to **SharingCriteriaRule** and **SharingTerritoryRule** and nothing changed. Where this field should be present?

This is how does look my modified `createSHaringRule` method:

```
// Create Sharing Rule
MetadataService.MetadataPort service = MetadataPortController.createService();
MetadataService.SharingRules testSharingRule = new MetadataService.SharingRules();
testSharingRule.fullName = 'Lead';
testSharingRule.sharingCriteriaRules = new List<MetadataService.SharingCriteriaRule>();
MetadataService.SharingCriteriaRule sharingCriteriaRule = new MetadataService.SharingCriteriaRule();
sharingCriteriaRule.fullName = 'TestCriteria';
sharingCriteriaRule.accessLevel = 'Read';
sharingCriteriaRule.label = 'Test';
sharingCriteriaRule.sharedTo = new MetadataService.SharedTo();
sharingCriteriaRule.sharedTo.allPartnerUsers = '';
sharingCriteriaRule.sharedFrom = new MetadataService.SharedTo();
sharingCriteriaRule.sharedFrom.allPartnerUsers = '';
sharingCriteriaRule.criteriaItems = new List<MetadataService.FilterItem>();
MetadataService.FilterItem cirteriaFilterItem = new MetadataService.FilterItem();
cirteriaFilterItem.field = 'RecordTypeId';
cirteriaFilterItem.operation = 'equals';
cirteriaFilterItem.value = 'Record Type A';
sharingCriteriaRule.criteriaItems.add(cirteriaFilterItem);
testSharingRule.sharingCriteriaRules.add(sharingCriteriaRule);
testSharingRule.sharingOwnerRules = new List<MetadataService.SharingOwnerRule>();
MetadataService.SharingOwnerRule sharingOwnerRule = new MetadataService.SharingOwnerRule();
sharingOwnerRule.fullName = 'TestOwner';
sharingOwnerRule.accessLevel = 'Read';
sharingOwnerRule.label = 'Test';
sharingOwnerRule.sharedTo = new MetadataService.SharedTo();
sharingOwnerRule.sharedTo.allPartnerUsers = '';
sharingOwnerRule.sharedFrom = new MetadataService.SharedTo();
sharingOwnerRule.sharedFrom.allInternalUsers = '';
testSharingRule.sharingOwnerRules.add(sharingOwnerRule);
testSharingRule.sharingTerritoryRules = new List<MetadataService.SharingTerritoryRule>();
MetadataService.SharingTerritoryRule sharingTerritoryRule = new MetadataService.SharingTerritoryRule();
sharingTerritoryRule.sharedTo = new MetadataService.SharedTo();
sharingTerritoryRule.sharedTo.allPartnerUsers = '';
sharingTerritoryRule.sharedFrom = new MetadataService.SharedTo();
sharingTerritoryRule.sharedFrom.allPartnerUsers = '';
testSharingRule.sharingTerritoryRules.add(sharingTerritoryRule);
List<MetadataService.SaveResult> results = service.createMetadata(new MetadataService.Metadata[] {
    testSharingRule
}
);
SharingRulesController.handleSaveResults(results[0]);
```

Comment: compile time or runtime error?

Comment: @cropredy yes, I am also getting same issue. It is a compile error